# Text Selection with CRichEditCtrl in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, win32gui

I have CRichEditCtrl object which is read only(Text is for read and not allowed to modified). I want to provide functionality of Text Selection with Mouse for text displayed with CRichEditCtrl object.

Following Code is working to capture event for Left Mouse Button - DOWN & UP

```
BOOL CReportFormView::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    if (m_EditNs->GetFocus()!=NULL) 
    {
        switch (pMsg->message)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                return TRUE;
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Now looking for some code to write in case block which will highlight selected text. I want to know if there is any API available for CRichEditCtrl object which help to track at which location user pressed Left Mouse Button and released

Comment: I can't understand your question. The RTF control does this selection by ist own. Event in read only mode? What is the reason to do it by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could use member function `CString strText = m_myRichEditCtrl.GetSelText();`  or some other member function. Like `GetSel()` just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the EM_CHARFROMPOS message. ex. some form of this:

```
POINTL pt { x,y }; // ... screen coordinates to test relative to edit 
DWORD info = m_EditNS->SendMessage(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, pt);
int charIndex = LOWORD(info);
int line = HIWORD(info);
```

After that, set the selection with normal selection methods.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761566(v=vs.85).aspx